# Scaling of First-passage times for Random Walk on integer lattices

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, random-walks, brownian-motion

Consider simple symmetric random walk $S_{n} = (S_{n}^{(1)},\dots,
S_{n}^{(d)})$ on the d-dimensional integer lattice with starting point the origin.

Let $\tau_{N}$ be the first time $S_{n}$ exits the box $[-N,N] \times \dots \times [-N,N]$. For $d \geq 2$, is anything known about the behaviour of $E(\tau_{N})$ as $N\rightarrow \infty$ ?

Pointers about the corresponding results for Brownian motion also very welcome.

Comment: Define $T_N$ as the time for $S_n^{(1)}$ to leave $[-N,N]$. 
Define $Z_N$ as the time for a 1-d symmetric random walk to leave $[-N,N]$ (the symmetric random walk can change every step and hence has distribution different from $S_n^{(1)}$).  Define $Z_N^{(i)}$ as independent versions of $Z_N$.  Then: 
$$ \min[Z_N^{(1)}, \ldots, Z_N^{(d)}] \leq_{st} \tau_N \leq_{st} T_N $$
where $\leq_{st}$ denotes “stochastically less than or equal to.”  I think expectations of both
upper and lower bounds are proportional to $N^2$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I think the joint distribution (and the expectation) of your lower bound depend on $d$ and it is not easy to calculate the expectation due to the dependency you refer to.

Comment: Well, I think the upper bound is exactly computable as $E[T_N] = d(N+1)^2$.  Do you agree that the lower bound is proportional to $N^2$? It would have expectation $\int_{0}^{\infty} Pr[Z_N^{(1)}>x]^ddx$, I think this can be used to show $N^2$ behavior (though the coefficient multiplier would be loose).

Comment: Another observation is that the system is similar to a continuous time system of $d$ independent 1-dimensional Markov random walks with forward step rate $\lambda$ and backward step rate $\lambda$. Your discrete-time walk is in fact the embedded chain of this continuous time system.

Comment: many thanks for your most helpful tips. Write $\tau$ for $\tau_{1}$. The $p_{n} = P(\tau \geq n)$ equals the sum of some convoluted trigonometric series, so that $\sum_{n \geq 0} p_{n}^{d}$ is not calculable. An implicit martingale argument for calculating gives $E(\min(\tau, k)) = E(S^{2}_{\min(\tau, k)})$, which leads me to $E(S_{k}^{2}| \tau>k)$. I.e, conditional that the 1-d walk is not absorbed by some time $k$, what is the expected distance of its position from the origin? I expect some arcsine law for this and thinking of re-posting the question hoping for a relatively simple answer.

Comment: the last question has now been posted in extended for here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/207665/arc-sine-law-for-distance-from-the-origin-for-random-walk-conditioned-to-non-abs

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain quickly bounds from above and below by considering the martingale 
$$
Y_n-dn:=\sum_{i=1}^d (S_n^{(i)})^2- dn.
$$
Then, at time $\tau_N$ we have the following estimate from below 
$$
Y_{\tau_N}\ge N^2,
$$
as one of the components is greater than $N^2$  than by the definition of $N$. The bound from above follows from the representation
$$
Y_{\tau_N}=Y_{\tau_N-1}+2\sum_{i=1}^d\xi_{\tau_N}^{(d)}S_{\tau_N-1}^{(d)}+\sum_{i=1}^d (\xi_{\tau_N}^{(d)})^2
$$
Now note that  $|S_{\tau_N-1}^{(d)}|\le N$ by the definition of $\tau_N$. Hence,
$$
Y_{\tau_N} \le dN^2+2dN+d=d(N+1)^2
$$
Now we can apply the optional stopping theorem to obtain 
$$
d\mathbf  E[\tau_N]=\mathbf E[Y_{\tau_N}],
$$
which we can combine with the above estimates to obtain 
$$
N^2\le d\mathbf E[\tau_N]\le d(N+1)^2.
$$
The upper and lower bounds have the same order. It is possible to get sharp asymptotics as well by using the approach in my answer  to [Stopping time of two dimensional random walk](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/166047/stopping-time-of-two-dimensional-random-walk/228564#228564)